# Can I write to a variable in a thread and read it in another thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I know that I can use semaphore or mutex and ..., but I like to know if there is any problem if I write to a variable in one thread and read it in another thread? something such as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

volatile int value=0;

int main()
{
     auto workerThread = new std::thread([&]()
        {
           for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
           {
                value=i;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(i*100));
            }
        }
     );

     while(true)
     {
            std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
            if(value >1000) break;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
     }
}
```

Is it a safe application and there is no smell in it?

Without any complexity, can I improve it?

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not "safe".

Whoever told you that `volatile` was what you needed to make this safe was *wrong*.

Either wrap access to `value` in a mutex or semaphore, or make it an `std::atomic<int>`.

Also note that:

```
std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
if(value >1000) break;
```

may each read different value. You may want to read it only once:

```
int v = value;
std::cout << v << std::endl;
if(v > 1000) break;
```

Comment: Thanks, If we forgot about the value which is read ( maybe different value is written, but read differently), is there any chance that the application crashes? If why?

Comment: @mans: Pick up a book on concurrent programming. This is not the place to conduct an introductory lecture on concurrency.

Comment: @mans: It can do anything, unsynchronized non-atomic access has undefined behavior. On x86, this specific read will never crash but it can easily make your application crash due to unexpected value or just a slight change can cause UB, eg. when using `bool` this way.